# WPF MVVM How to access collection of Rectangles from View in ViewModel?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I've got a button with RaisePropertyChanged in ViewModel which adds Rectangles from Shapes to the interface and to the ObservableCollection.

In the View, I have the functionality to moving around or resize selected Rectangles, by clicking on them. It has to be in View, because of the use Canvas, for example, like in Window_Loaded method.

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Rectangles = new List<Rectangle>();
            foreach (UIElement child in canvas1.Children)
            {
                if (child is Rectangle)
                    Rectangles.Add(child as Rectangle);
            }

            // Reverse the list so the Rectangles on top come first.
            Rectangles.Reverse();
        }
```

or canvas1_MouseDown

```
        private void canvas1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {

            FindHit(Mouse.GetPosition(canvas1));
            SetMouseCursor();
            if (MouseHitType == HitType.None) return;

            LastPoint = Mouse.GetPosition(canvas1);
            DragInProgress = true;
        }
```

Unfortunately, List Rectangles consists only "static" elements from UI, not those I'm adding by a button click. What I'm trying to do is instead to populate this List with rectangles I'm adding in ViewModel. Any suggestions are warmly welcome.

What I tried to do it's to count added rectangles and just populate Rectangles using the same amount of new objects, but it looks like it should have properties of the objects on the interface to allow interaction.

Answer (score 3):

This assumes you have an `ObservableCollection` called `Shapes` in your VM of some kind of `ShapeVM` object which has appropriate properties (eg `RectVM` with Width and Height etc)

The `ItemsControl` will automatically add them to the view when the underlying collection changes.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Shapes}">

    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:RectVM}">

            <Rectangle Canvas.Left="{Binding X}" 
                       Canvas.Top="{Binding Y}" 
                       Width="{Binding Width}"
                       Height="{Binding Height}" />

        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>

</ItemsControl>
```

Note that this kind of binding is not appropriate if you're going to have thousands of shapes, since performance will be an issue.